# Multiple roles with social signup meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

In my app I have 2 registration buttons (facebook):

- Broadcaster registration
- Regular User registration

Both buttons are currently generated by

```
{{> loginButtons}}
```

So this is basically the same form.

I want to add the correct role to the newly registered user (broadcaster/normal user), based on what form he used to signup. But I don't know how I can add extra parameters to the signup buttons.

When searching for a solution I found that you could use the server side method **Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user)** to assign the correct roles. But at that point I don't know what signup form the user has used.

Is there any way to have multiple social signup buttons and insert the correct role for that user ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `Meteor.loginWithFacebook` method doesn't allow passing extra options. But you can create your own button that logs the user in, and then makes sure the user has the appropriate rights:

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook((error) => {
  if (!error) Meteor.call("assign-role", "broadcaster");
});
```

To make this work, you'll have to write your own "assign-role" method of course.

Comment: Okay, I understand that I need to create my own server side method. But still how can I find what button is used in the loginWithFacebook ?

Comment: That's client side code in my answer. Just make two versions of it, and bind them to your two buttons.

Comment: How do I bind them to it ? Could you give an example ? It's not clear to me. Pretty new to Meteor :)

Comment: Well, by the end of the Meteor tutorial, you'll know it. :) https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app